# Is It possible to export constructor function and some normal function from same module in node js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, node-modules

My app structure:

```
| my-application
| -- app.js
| -- node_modules
| -- public
| -- models
     | -- users.js
| -- routes
     | -- index.js
| -- views
     | -- index.ejs
```

**users.js**

```
function User(name){
   this.name = name;
}

User.prototype.getName = function () {
   return this.name;
};

exports.checkName = function (name) {
   if(name === 'johnSnow'){
      return true;
   }
   return false;
};

module.exports = User;
```

And i try this:

**index.js**

```
var user  = require('../models/users');

if( user.checkName('dinar') === true ){
    var User = new user('name');
    console.log(User.getName());
}
```

**`TypeError: user.checkName is not a function`**

Is it possible to use functions and constructor function from same module?

Is there any way to do this?

I'm new in node js.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: You've defined it as `exports.checkName`, but you're exporting User. It should be `User.prototype.checkName`, same as `User.prototype.getName`

Comment: You're only exporting a single thing with your last line.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it's possible, by putting the normal function as a "static" method on the constructor function itself. In your attempt, you were overwriting the `exports` object with `User` so the `checkName` was lost. Instead, do

```
function User(name){
   this.name = name;
}

User.prototype.getName = function () {
   return this.name;
};

User.checkName = function (name) { /*
^^^^ */
   return name === 'johnSnow';
};

module.exports = User;
```

Or alternatively you might want to write

```
module.exports = User;
module.exports.checkName = function (name) {
   return name === 'johnSnow';
};
```

Comment: So it's without prototype.Thanks for your answer.

Comment: "Static" is without the `.prototype`, yes, because the prototype is for instances

Answer (score 2):

For this type of implementation you would usually do:

in ***user.js***

```
function User(name){
    this.name = name;
}
User.prototype.getName = function () {
    return this.name;
};

module.exports = {
    User: User,
    checkName: function(name) {
        return (name === 'johnSnow');
    }
};
```

and then in ***index.js***

```
var users  = require('../models/users');

if (users.checkName('dinar')) {
    var user = new users.User('name');
    console.log(user.getName());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It is quite possible and would do it like this this. For me I always write functions belonging to an object as nested functions, I find it conceptually easier and more logical. You'll see that addSquares is a helper method that does not belong to the Square objects made from the constructor function.

**FileA:**

```
var exports = module.exports();
exports.Square = Square;
exports.addSquares = addSquares;

function Square(width, height){
   this.width = width;
   this.height = height;

   this.area = function(){
       return this.width * this.height;
   }
}

function addSquares(sq1, sq2){
   return sq1.getArea() + sq2.getArea();
}
```

**fileB**

```
var Square = require('fileA');

var mySquare = new Square.Square(10,50);
var yourSquare = new Square.Square(50,50);
var area2 = Square.addSquares(mySquare, yourSquare);
```